# Python Popen - how to execute commands in nested sub shell using python

Tags: python, subprocess

"I have an issue executing commands in nested adb sub shell in python. executing "command_two" in adb shell opens a sub console in command line (and the console waits for input). how do i execute commands (give input to the console) in that console using the python.

### Code:

```
     R = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
     R.communicate('command_one\ncommand_two\n)
```

Comment: You can try to divide commands to 3 calls of `communicate` and insert pause between them and try to add `shell=True` parameter for `Popen`

Comment: do you mean: 
R.communicate('command_one'')
R.communicate('command_two')
R.communicate('command_three)

and How do i add Pause in between them. @RomanMindlin

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import time

R = subprocess.Popen('adb shell', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
R.communicate('command_one\n')
time.sleep(2)
R.communicate('command_two\n')
```