# Execute commands in Python without closing the CMD shell

Tags: windows, python-3.x, shell, command-line

I'm trying to execute commands sequentially through Python.

My aim is to do something like this:

```
command1
calculate something
command2
...
```

I want the CMD to remain opened after executing 'command1' , since 'command2' **is dependent** on 'command1'.

I've tried these answers with no results:

This one gives me the error:

```
ValueError: write to closed file
```

while executing two communicate commands.

[Python Popen - how to execute commands in nested sub shell using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600399/python-popen-how-to-execute-commands-in-nested-sub-shell-using-python)

[Execute Commands Sequentially in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359347/execute-commands-sequentially-in-python)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only reason one might want to run multiple commands in a single shell is if the commands are dependent batch scripts that set environment variables. Otherwise use the subprocess module (`Popen` `run`, `check_output`, etc) and only use its `shell=True` argument for internal shell commands (e.g. `dir`, `copy`, etc).

Comment: Yes, the commands are dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
import os  
os.system("start cmd /k command1 & command2")
```

unless you want it to quit after execting **both** of the commands:

```
import os
os.system("start cmd /c command1 & command2")
```

If you want to add more commands add & after command 2 and write your commands.
the first example will run both of the commands in the same window, but won't close it.

the second example will run both of the commands in the same window, and **will** close it afterwards

Comment: Thank you. I want to allow sending commands to the cmd after it is opened, for example after several Python commands to execute another command...

Comment: I'm not sure... Can I use it to execute the sequence: os.system("start cmd /k command1 & command2")  
x=x+1
os.system("start cmd /k command3 & command4")  
so that command3 and 4 will be in the same window?

Comment: I don't think so. If you can provide more of your code I might be able to help you more.

Comment: I want to execute several commands, in different parts of my code. For example: I have 3 commands: vivado -mode tcl (this command opens communication with a program I use)
open_hw
connect_hw_server
(these commands are executed by the program). I want to execute the first command and then continue with my code a bit, and after several commands in Python to execute the other 2 commands.

Comment: If you could provide more of the code, I could maybe help you to rewrite it so that it would not be needed.

Comment: does 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se) help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177475/discussion-between-orohev-and-kozova1).